# setting minimum date in jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have to set the minimum date in the jQuery datepicker.

Only allowed values are 1st of the next three months. So I want the calendar to open to the next month instead of existing month.

when I set the min Date to +1M it does open Jan 2014 calendar instead of dec 2013 but the 1st of that month is disabled.

If I set minDate to -0, I see dec calendar with no valid select option as 1st has already passed. The user has to go to next month to and the 1st is selectable.
My code is:

```
$("#effdatepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    minDate: "+1M",
    maxDate: "+3M",
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (jQuery('#enddatepicker').val() != "") {
            jQuery(this).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', jQuery('#enddatepicker').val());
        }

    },
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        //getDate() returns the day (0-31)
        if (date.getDate() == 1) {
            return [true, ''];
        }
        return [false, ''];
    }

});
```

Comment: If you set it to +1M you’re basically telling it +1 month from TODAY. So on Dec 5 it’s going to show Jan 5 and on.

Comment: I removed my answer because it was of no practical value to the OP. In general you can also apply a Date() object to `minDate`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153930/jquery-datepicker-show-next-month-if-near-the-end-of-current-month) - maybe it can help you.

Comment: Basically someone is gonna have to write a custom function to check the current month and set a variable value to +1 month based on name only. Then that variable is going to need to be inserted into the `datePicker` params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var d  = new Date();
    d2 = new Date(),
    m  = d.getMonth(),
    y  = d.getFullYear();

d.setFullYear(m > 10 ? y+1 : y, (m < 11 ? m + 1 : 0), 1);
d2.setFullYear(m+3 > 10 ? y+1 : y, (m+3 < 11 ? m + 3 : (m + 3)-12), 1);

$("#effdatepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    minDate: d,
    maxDate: d2,
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (jQuery('#enddatepicker').val() != "") {
            jQuery(this).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', jQuery('#enddatepicker').val());
        }

    },
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        //getDate() returns the day (0-31)
        if (date.getDate() == 1) {
            return [true, ''];
        }
        return [false, ''];
    }
}).datepicker('setDate', d)
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Zzm/2/)

Comment: sorry, i am getting 1/1/2013 instead of 1/1/2014

Comment: @Abbi - forgot the years, edited the answer to account for that as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This does work exactly like I need. I just started with your idea and got it in a simpler way below. But Thanks, your example did help me a lot.

Comment: @Abbi - Setting the month to a number higher than 11 will increase the year and do what you want as well, and it is how the date object is supposed to work, I just don't like to rely on that feature being implented in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing like this.

```
var d = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();

d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
d.setDate('1');
d2.setMonth(d2.getMonth() + 3);
d2.setDate('1');

$("#effdatepicker").datepicker({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
buttonImageOnly: true,
minDate: d,
maxDate: d2,
beforeShow: function () {
    if (jQuery('#enddatepicker').val() != "") {
        jQuery(this).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', jQuery('#enddatepicker').val());
    }

},
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    //getDate() returns the day (0-31)
    if (date.getDate() == 1) {
        return [true, ''];
    }
    return [false, ''];
}
}).datepicker('setDate', d)
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0808/QpxGr/1/)